# Passing a password to a web service and storing it

Tags: c#, postgresql, security, passwords

What is the proper way of passing a password to a web service via restful api (when a user is registering or just logging in)? How should I store it?

From what I was thought, I should only store hashes, for example MD5. But from what I can read in the Internet it appears to be rather easy to just look up a hash in a "hash rainbow table" - so storing a hash would be equal to storing a clear text. How to do it properly?

Info:

- .NET, C#
- PostgreSQL

Comment: don't use md5. it's essentially "broken" in cryptographic terms. use sha-256, with proper salting.

Comment: There's an OWASP recommendation on that https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: A ton of examples exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to pass username and password to a REST service is to use the [basic authentication scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617) over HTTPS. HTTPS should protect your password from being stolen in transit.

As I explain in [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136934/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-send-username-and-password-with-every-request-between-mo/27138900#27138900), it's not a good idea to use basic authentication for your services. You would be better of using a Security Token Service ([STS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_token_service)) and use bearer authentication

Comment: +1 for refering OAuth2 in your linked answer, it could be a good solution for the given question. Here is a [brief](http://blog.cloudfoundry.org/2012/10/09/oauth-rest/) example on how to secure restful web services. For authentication i would combine it with [openID](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/)

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, where did I say that basic auth is good? Sometimes it's the only option you have.