# HTTP Basic authentication (Java / Jersey)

Tags: java, web-services, rest, security

I created `REST webservice` and secured it using `HTTP Basic authentication`.

It working fine, and asking for the `username/password`. 
But on second run (if browser still open) the webservice does not ask for `username/password`. If I close and reopen browser, it work as I wanted - asking to authentication.

I want webservice ask for username/password on every run (no matter if other web page is open or not).

Any idea what should I do?

Comment: Maybe your browser is caching credentials no ?

Comment: This is probably nothing to worry about. With HTTP Basic, the client of your webservice has to authenticate every request using a username and password. Try testing your service using a REST client like Postman (instead of a browser) to see how it behaves. Like Blackus said, your browser is probably just caching the credentials, but that doesn't mean they don't get sent every time.

Comment: you can write unit test cases to assure same..

Comment: If you move away from Basic Auth to some custom strategy the browser won't be able to "help" the user by autofilling the credentials. Perhaps passing the uname/pwd in a form field or custom header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the basic authentication scheme is an [implicit authentication](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/04/01/implicit-vs-explicit-authentication-in-browser-based-applications/) scheme.

Once authenticated, the browser will automatically include the credential on subsequent requests. The only way to prevent this is to open an anonymous session or close the browser. These authentication schemes are vulnerable to [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) attacks.

There are other reasons to prefer other authentication schemes over basic authentication as I discuss in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136934/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-send-username-and-password-with-every-request-between-mo/27138900#27138900).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way around this: The browser will send the user/pw with every request until you close it.